# How to use while and until loops on active records in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called houses, I need to get a list of houses, like '@houses = House.where(...)'

and then check each of them using some method(not just a simple where) until I will get record that matches (when the method returns true).

I've only used .each so far. How do I go to check the next record in the list using an UNTIL or WHILE loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) for this purpose?

```
@houses = House.where(...)
@house = @houses.detect { |h| your condition here }
```

Comment: If using `Enumerable`, you can use its [detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) method instead, which returns the first object from the collection that the block returns true for

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky you're right, I misunderstood the question a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
@houses = House.where(...)
status = @houses.detect { |h| your condition here }.present?
return for you true/false
```